# Two Definitions for 'This' Method

Tags: c#, overriding

Is it possible to have 2 definitions for the `this` method? I want users to be able to do both of the following: `string value = myBranch[stringKey];` and also `Branch child = myBranch[stringKey]`.

Is this possible? And if not can you suggest how I could design my class to achieve the same outside interaction (ie, accessing a child branch or value easily)?

```
public class Branch {
    public enum BranchType  {TYPE_BRANCH, TYPE_LEAF}
    private string key                              = null;
    private string value                            = null;
    private Branch parent                           = null;
    private Dictionary <string, Branch> children    = new Dictionary <string, Branch>();

    // Is it possible to have 2 'this' definitions?
    // Def 1:
    public Branch this[string attribKey] {
        get
        {
            if (this.children.ContainsKey(attribKey))
                return this.children[attribKey];

            return Branch.EmptyBranch;
        }
        set
        {
            children[attribKey] = value;
            value.Parent        = this;
            this.Type           = BranchType.TYPE_BRANCH;
        }
    }

    // Def 1:
    public string this[string attribKey] {
        get 
        { 
            return value; 
        }   
        set 
        {
            value = value;
        }
    }

    public string Key {
        get { return key; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the one rule for overloads is that **Overloads cannot differ only by return value**. Since `myBranch` is probably a Dictionary, it doesn't make sense that it would sometimes return a `string` and sometimes a `Branch`. I would write two functions:

`GetBranchByKey` and `GetStringByKey` to solve the overload problem.